# Is there a more efficient way to organize random outcomes by size in Python?

Tags: python, random

I'm making a program that, in part, rolls four dice and subtracts the lowest dice from the outcome. The code I'm using is

```
die1 = random.randrange(6) + 1
die2 = random.randrange(6) + 1
die3 = random.randrange(6) + 1
die4 = random.randrange(6) + 1
if die1 <= die2 and die1 <= die3 and die1 <= die4:
    drop = die1
elif die2 <= die1 and die2 <= die3 and die2 <= die4:
    drop = die2
elif die3 <= die1 and die3 <= die2 and die3 <= die4:
    drop = die3
else:
    drop = die4

cha = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4 - drop
```

That's the best I could come up with from my so-far limited coding ability. Is there a better way to make it organize the four dice in order of size, then add together the three highest while ignoring the leftover? Or is the code I'm using the best way to do it?

Comment: just a tip, random.randrange accepts a start parameter. Use `random.randrange(1, 7)` to avoid adding 1 to the result.

Comment: I thought it was random.randint that did that, and randrange had to be a single number representing a random from 0 to that number. Although now that I look at the code again I should have used 5 instead of 6

Comment: If in doubt, see the documentation. randrange: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange and randint: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: Show of hands: how many here read this question and immediately thought of D&D character stats?  (\*raises hand\*)

Comment: lol thats exactly what it is. I'm making an NPC generator for python practice :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the dice in a list, sort the list using [**`sorted`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) and remove the smallest element using a slice:

```
>>> import random
>>> dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(4)]
>>> sum(sorted(dice)[1:])
13
```

Or an alternative that is simpler and will also be faster if you have lots of dice: use [**min**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) to find the minimum die and subtract it from the sum of them all:

```
>>> sum(dice) - min(dice)
13
```

Comment: so 

dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(4)]
sum(dice) - min(dice)

replaces that entire block I posted? lol I wasted a lot of time it looks like. is x a variable or is that just part of the function?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, that is all you need. The `x` is an unused variable.

Comment: Fun tip: You may use `_` as a placeholder for an unused variable. For example: `[random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]`

Comment: Since the `_` variable has a special meaning in interactive sessions (it contains the last result), I recommend not using as suggested here.

Comment: If min is simpler *and* faster than your first solution, then it should be preferred?

Comment: @Paul Hankin: Yes. The only reason why I wrote the first solution is because that was how the problem was described and that's the approach I first used. As far as I can see the first approach is only useful if you have to remove the x lowest dice for x > 1.